# ImageView On click not firing at the 2nd click

Tags: android, imageview, popupmenu

I want to close a popup menu on clicking a imageview.But it is not working.

```
menuicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (f == 1) {
            f = 0;
            mPopupMenu.setContentWidth(ContactsActivity.this.getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay()
                .getWidth() / 2);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mPopupMenu.setAnchorView(menuicon);
            mPopupMenu.show();

        } else {
            mPopupMenu.dismiss();
            f = 1;

        }

    }
});
```

When I click the menuicon first time the popup menu is displaying correctly.But when i click for the 2nd time the menu is not closing.I debugged my code and found that the imageview is actually not firing roe 2nd time.menuicon is an imageview.And here is xml code:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menuicon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/menuicon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 

        />
```

Initial value of f is 1.

Comment: Tell me please what is mPopupMenu? If it popupWindow, look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setOutsideTouchable(boolean). I think this is what you need. But be carefull, you must call this method before you show your popup and setFocusable to false of your popup.

Comment: mPopupMenu is actually an object of IcsListPopupWindow.I am using actionbarsherlock over here and dismiss method is defined within that IcsListPopupWindow class.The dismiss function is working fine in other cases.

Comment: I've looked throw it's source, I think you need call setModal(false) for this popup.

Comment: @Demand...thanx a lot man...it is working now...post this as answer and I eill accept it...Thak u once again :)

Comment: Demand...now there is another problem.Menu Items are not responding on clicking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call setModal(false) of mPopupMenu. It will call setFocusable of inner PopupWindow  and allow you to get events in the background window.

Comment: @Demand...now there is another problem.Menu Items are not responding on clicking.

Comment: @Demand..pls have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645985/imageview-on-click-not-firing-at-the-2nd-click-part-2